# Non-store value ExtJs

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4.2

So I'm trying to create an 'abnormal' combobox using ExtJs 4 and I'm running into a slight issue which I can't figure out how to resolve. I got the basics down with the code that follows. As of right now I am able to get the dropdown to show all the addresses in a proper format and when I click on the proper address it properly shows the 'Street1' value in the input.

Here is what I'm stuck on:
I'm trying to add an initial item to the combobox that basically says something like 'Add New Address' that the user can select. (I'm planning on having this open a modal where the user can input a new address, save it and then have it be displayed back in the combobox, but all of that should be fairly simple) I can't seem to figure out a way of adding just a simple 'Add New Address' and then tracking the value to see if that value is returned to know to make the modal appear or not. I don't want to add it to the store as (I assume) that will add an item in the database and I'd prefer that not happen for the 'Add New Address'.

Any thoughts on how to get that to work? From below you can see that LocationStore is my store and that the general address components apply.

Thank you in advance.

ComboBox Code:

```
{
     xtype: 'combobox',
     anchor: '100%',
     listConfig: {
         emptyText: 'Add New Address - Empty Text',
         itemTpl: '<tpl if="Name">{Name}<br /></tpl>'+'<tpl if="Street1">{Street1}<br /></tpl>'+'<tpl if="Street2">{Street2}<br /></tpl>'+'{City}, {StateOrProvince} {PostalCode}'
     },
     emptyText: 'Add New Location - tester',
     fieldLabel: 'Street 1',
     name: 'Street1',
     allowBlank: false,
     blankText: 'Street 1 Required',
     displayField: 'Street1',
     forceSelection: true,
     store: 'LocationStore',
     typeAhead: true,
     valueField: 'Street1',
     valueNotFoundText: 'Add New Location'
 },
```

Comment: Where have you found `itemTpl`? I can't see it in the doc.

Comment: Why don't you add this 'Add New Location' record to the store?

Comment: @rixo http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig If you look at the comments you'll see it within there

Comment: @sha because conceptually 'Add New Location' is not a location.... I want to keep the database clean from stuff like that especially since you can't determine where that item will show up and I need it to show up first.

Comment: Try to set `emptyText` instead of `valueNotFoundText`

Comment: @sha I just updated my code. 'Add New Location' never shows up (oddly enough), 'Add New Location - tester' shows up as a placeholder, and 'Add New Address - Empty Text' does show up properly in the dropdown menu, but I can't seem to get it to be clickable at all.

Comment: I dont think you can make it clickable. Try to subscribe to change event and see if get it fired when you select this empty line.

Comment: @sha That's what I had already tried with no success. It seems like by default it's not clickable in anyway so that the change event doesn't even get triggered =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to those who pointed me to the right place in the doc, I finally found it!

I managed to achieve what you want by using the `tpl`, unfortunately I could not find a way to make the keyboard navigation work for the added item. I've looked at the code of [`Ext.view.BoundListKeyNav`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundListKeyNav), but didn't find any easy solution...

The key was to use `tpl` instead of `itemTpl`, and add the markup for the extra item before the `for` loop:

```
listConfig: {
    tpl: '<div class="my-boundlist-item-menu">Add New Address</div>'
        + '<tpl for=".">'
        + '<div class="x-boundlist-item">' + itemTpl + '</div></tpl>'
    ,listeners: {
        el: {
            delegate: '.my-boundlist-item-menu'
            ,click: function() {
                alert('Go go go!');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code in on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/DMq2z).

Comment: Nice! I was trying to get BoundList to force an item to be added. I was able to get it so that an item was added, but none of the event listeners were working on it. This is the perfect solution! Thanks a mill

Answer (score 0):

@rixo see the comments on sencha api:

[Config: Ext.form.field.ComboBoxView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig)

---

**ADD VALUE:**

Maybe we can use [Sencha merge object function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-merge)...

To put 'add new location' value at the store top:

```
var newLocation = { 'Street' : 'Add New Location' };
var dataMerged = Ext.Object.merge(newLocation,myStore.getRange());
myStore.loadData(dataMerged);
```

**SORT:**

1. add **name** config param to your combobox
2. On controller: (2 ways)

   'nameComboView combobox[name=combo]' : {

   ```
   select : this.function1, // <-- when you select a item
   change : this.funciton2  // <-- when the item select are changing
   ```

   }
3. Now, on function, compare the value to open modal window or not.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without loading the data? I want to use the store in other locations without the 'Add New Location' in there. So merge might work, but I'd want to add it to the <ul> directly without adding it to the store.

Comment: You can to do:

myStore.add({some: 'data'}); , but maybe it won't be the first data.

Comment: I think you're missing the point that I don't want to add data to the store. If I add data to the store that piece of data will be added to all other components of the application. I need it added to the combobox without adding it to the store... That's what makes this a lot harder =p